# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save() Error how to fix?

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function AddArtWork(Request $request){
    $art = new Artwork;
    $art->name = $request->name;
    $art->date = $request->date;        

    if (!is_null($request->paintStyle)) {
        # code...
        $paint = new Paint;
        $paint->style = $request->paintStyle;
        $art->paint()->save($paint);
    }
    else if (!is_null($request->calligStyle)) {
        # code...
        $callig = new Calligraphy;
        $callig->style = $request->calligStyle;
        $art->calligraphie()->save($callig);
    }
    else if (!is_null($requst->substance)) {
        # code...
        $sclup = new Sculpture;
        $sculp->substance = $request->substance;
        $art->sculpture()->save($sculp);
    }

    if (!is_null($request->recievedDate)) {
        # code...
        $loan = new Loan;
        $loan->date = $request->loanDate;
        $art->loan()->save($loan);
    }

    else if (!is_null($request->storeOrexpose)) {
        # code...
        $perm = new Permanent_collection;
        $perm->ExposeOrStore = $request->storeOrexpose;
        $art->permanent()->save($perm);
    }

    $art->save();
    return redirect('addartwork');
}
```

This is the function in my controller and when i use it it triggers the following error and i dont know what is wrong in my code.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::save()
```

my page view is:
[image]

i am trying to save request in the function but it doesn't work.
if you know how to fix this plz explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This occurs cause your `ArtWork` object doesn't exist in database , you didn't save them. And when you try set relation on your object Laravel try to find his *id* and fail to do this.
Before saving relations for model you should save the model itself.

This should work

```
public function AddArtWork(Request $request){
    $art = new Artwork;
    $art->name = $request->name;
    $art->date = $request->date;   
    $art->save();     

    if (!is_null($request->paintStyle)) {
        # code...
        $paint = new Paint;
        $paint->style = $request->paintStyle;
        $art->paint()->save($paint);
    }
    else if (!is_null($request->calligStyle)) {
        # code...
        $callig = new Calligraphy;
        $callig->style = $request->calligStyle;
        $art->calligraphie()->save($callig);
    }
    else if (!is_null($requst->substance)) {
        # code...
        $sclup = new Sculpture;
        $sculp->substance = $request->substance;
        $art->sculpture()->save($sculp);
    }

    if (!is_null($request->recievedDate)) {
        # code...
        $loan = new Loan;
        $loan->date = $request->loanDate;
        $art->loan()->save($loan);
    }

    else if (!is_null($request->storeOrexpose)) {
        # code...
        $perm = new Permanent_collection;
        $perm->ExposeOrStore = $request->storeOrexpose;
        $art->permanent()->save($perm);
    }

    return redirect('addartwork');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` does not have `save` method. Use `update` or `insert`.

`save` method is exists in `Model.php` (`Eloquent`). Your models must be extends from `Model` and then you can use `save`.

Comment: i already extends my models from model.then what is the problem."class Artwork extends Model"

Comment: Others models extends from Model? What code line causes the error?

Comment: all of them extends.the error is "Builder.php line 2161" and it's not trackable for me.

Answer (score 0):

you are saving `$art` in different if else condition.Like below

```
$art->paint()->save($paint);
$art->calligraphie()->save($callig);
$art->sculpture()->save($sculp);
```

Please look when you save `$art` with relation `$art` is a new instance,if it is a new instance how can you make relation of that and save relation.You can save relation if it is and existing row,without a  existing it will not found any relation,so relation will not save

Comment: i already did it.i extends.if you use php artisan make:model it creates one class with it by default.it is exactly make me confused.i can't undrestand what is the problem